# I'm trying to change the syntax in this code

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in Javascript. I just wonder how I can use style instead of using a new var in this code.

```
 var style =
"position:absolute;" +
"width:" + newObj.radius + "px;" +
"left:" + newObj.xPos + "px;" +
"top:" + newObj.yPos + "px;";
newImg.setAttribute("style", style);
```

I want the plus signs to be removed from the end of each line. I tried the following code, but it doesn't work.

```
newImg.style.position = "absolute;";
newImg.style.width= newObj.radius + "px;";
newImg.style.left = newObj.xPos + "px;";
newImg.style.top = newObj.yPos + "px;";
```

Comment: If you're using modern Javascript(ES6+), you can use template literal https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Sam - did the below work for you? Please mark as answered if it has

Answer (score 3):

You question is how to set HTML element's CSS attributes using `_Object_.style`'s properties vs. setting a style using `string` value

Like this:

```
newImg.style.position = "absolute";
newImg.style.width= newObj.radius + "px";
newImg.style.left = newObj.xPos + "px";
newImg.style.top = newObj.yPos + "px";
```

All of these can be found in [CSS Reference documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref) - look for Javascript syntax for each property

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById("theIdYouMadeInHTML").style.property = new style;
```

As shown in here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp